# Actualizar la base de datos de empleados mediante React js

Tags: mysql, reactjs

soy nuevo en react, lo que estoy haciendo es básicamente una pagina que tenga los nombres de los empleados en el que se pueda registrar, eliminar y editar la información del empleado y todos los registro están siendo guardados en una base de datos de MYSQL. Ya pude registrar y eliminar, pero el problema es editar la información.

Lo que hice es crear varios estados como cuando hice el registro de los empleados, luego llamar la tabla de los empleados que están en MYSQL y filtrarlos por el id según el empleado que quiera editar, lo que devuelve un array de la persona con toda su información.(Hasta ahí todo bien)

El problema que tengo es que que no se como "agarrar" de forma individual la información del empleado y para colmo solo me actualiza el nombre y no el resto de la información.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Axios from "axios";



const Editar = () => {

  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState()
  const [numeroDocumento, setNumeroDocumento] = useState()
  const [fechaNacimiento, setFechaNacimiento] = useState()
  const [pais, setPais] = useState()
  const [experiencia, setExperiencia] = useState()
const {id} = useParams()


//Aca seria que cada vez que aprieto el boton "Actualizar", toda la informcacion 
//se actualizara en mi base de datos
const update= () =>{
        Axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/update`,{
          id:id,
          nombre:nombre,
          numeroDocumento:numeroDocumento,
          fechaNacimiento:fechaNacimiento,
          pais:pais,
          experiencia:experiencia,
          
          
        }).then(()=>{
          
          alert("registrado")
        })
      }

//Aca es donde se llama todo la informcaion de los empleados que tengo en mi base de `datos y los filtra`
const getEmpleado = () =>{ 
        Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/empleados`).then((response)=>{
          const res = response.data.filter((item) => item.Id === parseInt(id));
          setNombre(res.map(item => item.Nombre))
          setNumeroDocumento(res.map(item => item.NumeroDocumento))
          setFechaNacimiento(res.map(item => item.FechaNacimiento))
          setPais(res.map(item => item.Pais))
          setExperiencia(res.map(item => item.Experiencia))
        })
      }

 useEffect(() =>{
        
          getEmpleado()
        
      },[])
return (

<div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Nombre</span>
            <input type="text" defaultValue={nombre} onChange={(event) =>{setNombre(event.target.value)}} className="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Numero de Documento</span>
            <input type="number" value={numeroDocumento} onChange={(event) =>{setNumeroDocumento(event.target.value)}} className="form-control" placeholder="Numero de Documento" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Fecha de nacimiento</span>
            <input type="number" value={fechaNacimiento} onChange={(event) =>{setFechaNacimiento(event.target.value)}} className="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Pais</span>
            <input type="text" value={pais} onChange={(event) =>{setPais(event.target.value)}} className="form-control" placeholder="Pais" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Experiencia</span>
            <input type="number"value={experiencia} onChange={(event) =>{setExperiencia(event.target.value)}} className="form-control" placeholder="Experiencia" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
          </div>
  
            <button onClick={update} >Actualizar</button>
    
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que me filtre el array del empleado, separar su información así poder actualizarlo de forma individual. Pensé que lo tenia cuando hice le  `map()` , pero parece que solo me muestra la informática pero no me los "separa".

Según un video que vi, el tipo lo que hacia era `setNombre(res.data."el titulo dentro del array"))` y de esa forma actualizaba la información de forma individual, pero a mi me dice que res.data es **undefined**.

Estoy con este problema desde hace días y no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!